# Has anyone used superset as their customer analytics solution?

Tags: analytics, apache-superset

Interested to know if anyone has successfully implemented Superset as there customer analytics platform?

We are currently evaluating this, however, some struggle with restricting access to subsets of a dataset/source, or limit access to the specific row data.

For example companyB should only see data relevant to companyB. This is of course a mandatory requirement.

There are a lot of similar questions raised, so would be keen to know if someone has successfully accomplished this.

Comment: There currently isn't the ability to force filter to relevant data within a data source by row. However, you could add it. :)

Answer (score 2):

We are in the process of customizing superset to do something similar (without forking), though it doesn't involve row-level granularity. I was able to accomplish view-level access with a combination of [FAB permissions](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html) and a [custom security manager](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/13cbf80fb33b429273fadead85471cca7aac6d78/superset/__init__.py#L156-L161). Basically:

- User logs into superset through OAuth2 with our API.
- Security manager makes request to our API for a list of things the user can access.
- Superset builds datasources only for those items.

For this to work, we created a custom role that forbids users from doing things like creating new databases/tables, and add each user to that role once they log in. At this point, you may want to make a [connector](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/2362) for your own purposes so users can refresh datasources when they want/need to. Superset exposes a [config setting](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/13cbf80fb33b429273fadead85471cca7aac6d78/superset/config.py#L220-L224) for custom connectors so you don't have to modify source to load it. The [Druid](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/tree/master/superset/connectors/druid) connector is a good example of this.

So, to answer your question: sort of. Table-level/view-level access control is definitely doable, though it will be a bit of effort. Row-level access control? Probably not, unless your database engine of choice supports row-level access control.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer/advice. I've made quite a bit of evaluations on this and come to the conclusion that its too much of a "hack" for us and not viable for production use.However, we've incorporated Superset as one of our internal "BI" tools.